# jQuery .is('input:hidden') function returns true if any input type element is not visible

Tags: jquery

You can use the jQuery .is() function to determine if a html element is of a specific type.  For example,

```
$(x).is('input:text')
```

will return true if x references a

```
<input type="text'>
```

element.

I just noticed that if you make a text (or any other) input element invisible, then use `$(x).is('input:hidden')`, it always returns `TRUE`.

To actually match

```
<input type="hidden">
```

elements, you must do

```
$(x).is('input[type=hidden]')
```

Am I missing something here, or is this a bug?  I thought :hidden referred to the *element type*, not the *visibility* of the element.

Here's the requisite Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LzPdaj

Comment: This is the correct bahavior: [:hidden Selector](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, with jQuery method `is`, you are not exactly checking the element type, you are checking against a jQuery selector - https://api.jquery.com/is/

As for the selector, in CSS `:hidden` will match type hidden, but the same selector has a broader meaning in jQuery.

From the docs - https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

> Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:
>
> - They have a CSS display value of none.
> - They are form elements with type="hidden".
> - Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
> - An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.